# react native zss rich text editor toolbar actions does not work

Tags: react-native, toolbar, rich-text-editor

I have developed the Rich Text editor using react-native-zss-rich-text-editor but the toolbar actions does not work, who know how to fixed it? Thank you. Below is the code:

```
<RichTextToolbar
 getEditor={() => this.richtext}
 actions={defaultActions} // <= this actions does not work
 iconTint='black'
 selectedButtonStyle={{backgroundColor:'yellow'}}
/>
```

the defaultActions got defined in RichTextToolbar.js:

```
const defaultActions = [
  actions.insertImage,
  actions.setBold,
  actions.setItalic,
  actions.insertBulletsList,
  actions.insertOrderedList,
  actions.insertLink
];
```

This also got defined as the constants at here:

```
export const actions = {
...
setBold: 'bold',
setItalic: 'italic',
...
insertImage: 'INST_IMAGE',
...
insertBulletsList: 'unorderedList',
insertOrderedList: 'orderedList',
insertLink: 'INST_LINK',
...
}
```

...switch case here:

```
switch(action) {
 case actions.setBold:
 case actions.setItalic:
 case actions.insertBulletsList:
 case actions.insertOrderedList:
 case actions.insertImage:
  this.state.editor.prepareInsert();
   if(this.props.onPressAddImage) {
    this.props.onPressAddImage();
   }
 break;
```

But the actions does not work, please help and I will appreciate it. Thanks. I m using this library from the Github:

https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor

Comment: Did you figure it out? Mind sharing your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set default action in RichTextToolbar. I am using this without using any default action. Hope this help you

```
<RichTextEditor
    ref={(r)=>this.richtext = r}
    style={{
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        width:screen.width/100*80,
        height:screen.height/100*24,
    }}
    contentPlaceholder={'Type your post here...'}
    hiddenTitle={true}
    initialContentHTML={''}
    editorInitializedCallback={() => this.onEditorInitialized()}
/>
<RichTextToolbar
    getEditor={() => this.richtext}
    onPressAddImage={()=>{
        this.uploadImage();
     }}
    iconTint='black'
    selectedButtonStyle={{backgroundColor:'#51671d'}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import 'actions' from react-native zss-rich-text-editor

Like this:

```
import {RichTextEditor, RichTextToolbar, actions} from 'react-native-zss-rich-text-editor';
```

Then, in your RichTextToolBar, you just set actions like this:

```
actions={
              [
                actions.insertImage,
                actions.setBold,
                actions.setItalic,
                actions.insertBulletsList,
              ]
            }
```

The complete list of actions is here: https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor/blob/master/src/const.js